# How to change color of an element hovering on another element

Tags: html, css

I am wondering can I do something like that with CSS and how?

HTML:

```
<h2 id="hi">Hello!!! :) </h2>
<h3 id="bye">Bye!! :( </h3>
```

CSS:

```
#hi:hover {
     #bye {
          color: green;
     }
}
```

Comment: You can't, nested selectors are only found in preprocessors such as LESS, Sass, SCSS, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Like this maybe:

```
#hi:hover + #bye{
    color: green;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)